# Keeping cell blank if now values is added in IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying set IF condition, the conditions are working fine, only issue I am facing is that whenever the cell is left empty the resulting cell is still showing "Pass", but I want to keep it blank if nothing is entered in the cell

`=IF(B22<=2000,"Pass",IF(B22>2000,"Fail",""))`

Comment: Thank you guys, all of the suggestions worked...cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(B22="","",if(B22<=2000,"Pass","Fail"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested ISBLANK function works well for this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B22),"",IF(B22<=2000,"Pass","Fail"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
=IF(B22,IF(B22<=2000,"Pass","Fail"),"")
```

Note: the value in cell B22 needs to be either a number or blank (cannot be text).

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the following 2 ways

- =IF(ISBLANK(B22),"",IF(B22<2000,"Pass","Fail")) - Isblank used to check whether cell is empty or not.
- =IF(B22="","",IF(B22<2000,"Pass","Fail")) - here nested If conditions used to check cell values

Answer (score 0):

If the value (even if it is showing blank) in Cell `B22` is returned by a formula, then you probably want to use the following formula instead:

```
=IF(LEN(B22)=0,"",IF(B22>2000,"Fail","Pass"))
```